# How do I increase the rows of a textarea once its text length is greater than 52

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I dont wanna use autoGrow or JQuery elastic

Comment: if you don't want to use plugins which support exactly you need, why are you asking us for help?

Comment: elastic and autogrow have a default height and width and i only want it to grow when the length of the text if greater than 50 or 52

Comment: @Yash don't forget to accept an answer if one of them works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/ee992.php)

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
<textarea name="text" cols=65 rows=2 value=""> 
</textarea> 
</form><br><br> 
<script> 
    $(function(){ 
        $("textarea").keyup(function(){ 
            if ($(this).val().length > 52) { 
                 $(this).attr('rows', '15'); 
            } 
            //$("body").prepend($(this).val().length+'<br>'); 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: You have a typo. `lenght` should be `length` or `size()`.

Comment: @lolwut: Lol, I'm trying to google why lenght don't work in my code :D You got it!

Comment: What happens if the content of the textarea reaches the 15 rows you've set them to?  Or worse the textarea starts at 20 rows?

Comment: It was just demo. OP has to change it as he wants

Comment: SO's point isn't to code/program something for others, but to show @kasdega: them right direction

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified how much rows should be added to the textarea but I hope this answers your question. This code will work only if you have already set the default number of rows of your textarea in HTML, through the `rows` attribute.

```
$(function () {
    var rowsAdded = false;
    $("#myTextarea").keyup(function () {
        var textarea = $(this);
        if (textarea.val().length > 52 && !rowsAdded) {
             textarea.attr('rows', parseInt(textarea.attr('rows')) + rowsToAdd);
             // replace rowsToAdd with the number of rows to add to the textarea
             rowsAdded = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: close but not quite.  This will add "rowsToAdd" every time a keyup's after the length of the textarea has reached 52.  So if there are 52 chars in the textarea already and the user enters "abcd" rowsToAdd will be added 4 times.  http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/SKmUF/2/

Comment: @kasdega You are right. I edited the answer so that "rowsToAdd" will be added only once. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$(function () {
    $(".growingTextarea").bind("keyup", function () {
        var textarea = $(this);
        var currentRows = parseInt(textarea.attr('rows'));

        var isScrollable = textarea.scrollTop();        
        if(isScrollable) {
            textarea.attr('rows', currentRows+1);
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/SKmUF/

Comment: Of course this doesn't shrink the textarea if the KEYUP is a delete but you didn't ask for that.